# Return reference to struct in Go-lang

Tags: pointers, go, struct

I am having some thought issues with the following code

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

type Company struct {
    Name string
    Workers []worker
}

type worker struct {
    Name string
    Other []int
}

func (cmp *Company) NewWorker(name string) worker {
    wrk := worker{Name: name}
    cmp.Workers = append(cmp.Workers, wrk)
    return wrk
}

func main() {
    cmp := Company{}
    cmp.Name = "Acme"
    wrk := cmp.NewWorker("Bugs")
    for i := 1; i <= 10; i++ {
        wrk.Other = append(wrk.Other, i)
    }
    fmt.Println(wrk)
    fmt.Println(cmp)
}
```

https://play.golang.org/p/Bja7u148mg

As you can see the code is not returning the worker I am creating but a copy of it. How can I get it to return the actual worker? I have tried some variations of * and & on the different workers but I end up with either:

```
invalid indirect of worker literal (type worker)
```

or:

```
cannot use wrk (type worker) as type *worker in return argument
```

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
func (cmp *Company) NewWorker(name string) *worker {
    wrk := worker{Name: name}
    cmp.Workers = append(cmp.Workers, wrk)
    return &wrk
}
```

`&` always means "take the address of" (except for the binary bitwise operator version).  `*`, however, changes meaning depending on the context.  The expression `*Type` means "pointer to Type".  The express `*Pointer` means "the object that Pointer points to".  This is why you get an `invalid indirect of worker literal` if you try to use the expression `*wrk`, because you're saying "give me the object that `wrk` points to", but `wrk` isn't a pointer.

As such, you need `*worker` as your return type (returning a pointer to a worker), and you return `&wrk`, the address of the structure you're returning.

Another alternative is to use the built in `new()` to create a pointer in the first place:

```
func (cmp *Company) NewWorker(name string) *worker {
    wrk := new(worker)
    wrk.Name = name
    cmp.Workers = append(cmp.Workers, *wrk)
    return wrk // wrk is a pointer here
}
```

All that said, there's little reason to return a pointer to your worker structure here.  The structure itself only has two fields, both of which are already reference types (strings are essentially just immutable slices), so the entire structure is only 5 machine words long (so 20 or 40 bytes, depending on whether you're on 32bit or 64bit).  You're not modifying the struct after return, and the version you store in the Company struct is also a copy (Company holds a slice of workers, not a slice of pointers to workers).

Comment: The plan is to be able to use wrk in the main function to update the values of the same wrk in the Workers slice of cmp. Your first example does not do that. The second doesnt run in the playground `tmp/sandbox713099900/main.go:20: cannot use wrk (type *worker) as type worker in append
tmp/sandbox713099900/main.go:21: cannot use wrk (type *worker) as type worker in return argument`

Comment: Yep, made a type in the second one, my bad.  However, if you want to be able to update them within main, your slice in the Company structure needs to be of type `[]*worker`, a slice of pointers, and you need to append the address of the worker (so `append(cmp.Workers, &wrk)` for the first version and `append(cmp.Workers, wrk)` for the second version that uses `new()`), so the Company slice is referencing the same worker you return from the function via address.

Comment: Example with Company having a slice of pointers, showing it does in fact update in-place: https://play.golang.org/p/XAV1365jer